# Getting org.hibernate.AnnotationException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class FsetConsolidatedHoldings and its primary key put in FsetConsolidatedHoldingsPK. Similarly, I have the classes HolderType and HolderTypePK. I want to use variables in the HolderType class in a query including the inner join of FsetConsolidatedHoldings and HolderType

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "fset_consolidated_holdings", schema = "mket_data")
public class FsetConsolidatedHoldings extends HolderType{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1LL;

    @EmbeddedId
    private FsetConsolidatedHoldingsPK id;
    

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDate endDate;

    @Column(name = "fset_proper_name")
    private String fProperName;
```

This is the FSetConsolidatedHoldingsPK class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FsetConsolidatedHoldingsPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1LL;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fsym_id")
    private String fsymId;
```

This is the HolderType class

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "holder_type", schema = "mket_data")
@Inheritance
public class HolderType {
    @EmbeddedId
    private HolderTypePK holderTypeCode;

    @Column(name = "holder_type_description")
    private LocalDate holderTypeDescription;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;
```

This is the HolderTypePK class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HolderTypePK implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "holder_type_code")
    private String holderTypeCode;
}
```

I am getting the following error.
org.hibernate.AnnotationException:

com.ds.ind.hibernateEntities.FsetConsolidatedHoldingsPK must not have @Id properties when used as an @EmbeddedId: com.ds.ind.hibernateEntities.FsetConsolidatedHoldings.id

Comment: Why do you need the PKs with just a single property? Why not to use just @Id?

Comment: The framework is like that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be obvious from the exception but the issue is that `FsetConsolidatedHoldings` has 2 embeddedIds that is not allowed -- one it contains itself and the other is inherited from `HolderType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to annotate `FsetConsolidatedHoldingsPK` and `HolderTypePK` with `@Embeddable`